# Игнорирование mousemove на дочерних элементах

Tags: javascript, rangeslider

Из интереса попробовал написать `range slider`, что бы понять, как это должно работать, но столкнулся с проблемой:

```js
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
var button = document.querySelector('.button');

slider.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var lg = document.querySelector('.cursor');
  lg.innerHTML = 'Координаты мыши: ' + e.offsetX;
});
```

```css
.slider {
  background: blue;
  height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
}

.button {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 96px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="info">
  <span class="cursor"></span>
</div>
```

Должно работать так: вожу курсором по блоку `slider`, и обработчик события `mousemove` перемещает блок `button`.

**Проблема** заключается в том, что при наведении на блок `button`, событие возникает именно на нем. Есть ли способ игнорировать наведение на `button`, продолжая генерировать событие на `slider`?

Если нет, то каким ещё способом следует перемещать блок `button` внутри `slider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема не в генерировании события, а в  том, что вы берете `e.offsetX`,а при наведении на кнопку в `e` попадет кнопка, тоесть я предлагаю координаты брать с документа и отнимать от них оффсет слайдера с лева :

```js
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
var button = document.querySelector('.button');

slider.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var lg = document.querySelector('.cursor');
  lg.innerHTML = 'Координаты мыши: ' + (e.clientX - slider.offsetLeft);
});
```

```css
.slider {
  background: blue;
  height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
}

.button {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 96px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="info">
  <span class="cursor"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Так я и сделал в итоге. Но это не отменило моего интереса к тому, можно ли реализовать обработку событий так, что бы следить за координатами slider, даже если курсор над button. Есть ли у вас идеи? Или это единственный вариант?

Comment: @TryCatch как по мне, так событие так и останется тем, которое и есть и менять можно только то как мы получаем координаты

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за ответ